# DirectX 11 Blend

Tags: c#, directx-11

I'm using blends, but I'm not sure if this code will remove the color of all the textures in the transparent area or repaint the background color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Xev.png)

How should I solve it?

```
    {
    D3D11_BLEND_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));
    desc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = false;
    desc.IndependentBlendEnable = false;
    desc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = true;

    desc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
    desc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
    desc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

    desc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
    desc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
    desc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

    desc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

    HRESULT hr = graphics->GetDevice()->CreateBlendState(&desc, &blendState);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    graphics->GetDeviceContext()->OMSetBlendState(blendState, nullptr, 0xff);
}
```

Comment: You say "I'm not sure if this code will remove the color of all the textures in the transparent area or repaint the background color."  Does this mean you've tested it and it's not working the way you expect?  What expected results are you looking for that aren't being met?

Comment: Oh, I didn't attach an image. What I'm talking about is, I don't know why the results of this code are so derived.

Comment: ``src.rgb * src.a + dest.rgb * (1  - src.a)`` and for the alpha ``src.a``. This is assuming a straight alpha rather than premultipled alpha scheme. See [these blog posts](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html#premultipliedalpha)